# Reading telegram messages without adding a bot to a group

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

is it possible to automatically read messages from specific telegram groupchat(I am included in this groupchat) without adding bot to a group? Basically the goal is to process specific telegram messages using java, but without notifying ppl included in the group that bot is being used. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do with the messages?

Comment: Just process them as they come. I thought about some Telegram api that would fire a method whenever there is a new message. Ofcourse I would log in to Telegram using login api call. So far Telegram API looks quite confusing, its nowhere as neat as bot api, so I would be very grateful for any help from more experienced developer :)

Comment: @dev85 did you able to resolve your problem if yes what solution you found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bot cannot possibly read messages without adding the bot to a group, as that would be a security and privacy issue.  You can, however, make it slightly harder for people to notice by making sure not to have any commands listed with @botFather.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32577391/3817111).

Comment: Thank you for being helpful :). I don't see bot being a security breach because as I mentioned I have full access to messages. I mean I can set up a clicker that will copy all incoming messages. I just thought there is some better way, maybe a possibility to login with my account from java and get the messages with some request. Maybe turn my account into a bot :P. Thanks again.

Comment: Or Maybe achieve the same using only telegram API with username and password.

Comment: Oh!  By mentioning a bot you sort of limited my thought process there...  That should definitely be possible...

Comment: Great! :) Is there some example of personalized client online?

Comment: All or most of the clients are open sourced, you can find a list [here](https://telegram.org/apps#source-code).  You just need to find the code that gets messages and add whatever you want there.

Answer (score 1):

Why you wont try to add a bot to group?

```
https://telegram.me/[botname]?startgroup=foo
```